# My netbeans is not working after I deleted the jvm folder

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, java, jdk, netbeans

My netbeans is not starting since I deleted the `/usr/lib/jvm` folder. But I have installed `java jdk 1.7.0_51.deb` debian file and the file dir is `/usr/java`.

When I tried to start the `netbeans` using terminal the following message came out:

```
***Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object***
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `netbeans.conf` file available under `etc` folder.

Modify the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable to point to new JDK path, then restart your Netbeans.